# Ping 'Name or service not known' how can I clear cache

Tags: networking, networkmanager, cache, nslookup

For several days now, after several reboots I still am faced with the issue of my `CentOS 7` machine not being able to ping my domain.

```
[root@ip126 ~]# ping sub.mydomain.eu
ping: sub.mydomain.eu: Name or service not known
```

How am I able to clear whatever cache is preventing me from connecting to this address?

Comment: You cannot ping a *domain*; is that a domain name or a host name?

Comment: It's a hostname. It's the hostname of a proxmox server.

Comment: by using the text `sub.mydomain` and the phrasing `ping my domain`, you distract readers. Is your domain externally resolvable? If it's not private data, you could provide the actual domain name; otherwise, more details about your nameserver setup (/etc/resolv.conf) and which DNS servers you think should be able to answer the query.

Comment: `dig sub.mydomain.eu`. Your machine should not cache dns across boots: The time to live is, usually, to short to make it worth while.

Comment: Do you have network access? Who is your name server? does `dig sub.mydomain.eu @1.1.1.1` work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use nscd:

```
nscd -i hosts
```

Comment: I installed nscd and that done nothing. Am I supposed to do something after?

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear from the wording, but `nscd` *could have* interfered with your name resolution *if* it was running and configured; if you didn't have it installed, installing it is unlikely to help.